# Как сделать так, чтобы бот discord присылал сообщение автору реакции

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

У меня есть discord бот, и одна из его важных функций это отправка сообщения автору реакции от определенного сообщения. Но у меня возникает ошибка. Что я делаю не так, и как это исправить?

Код:

```
import discord
import time
from discord.utils import get
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    emoji = payload.emoji
    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    author = message.author
    if message.id==id of message:
        if emoji == ":flag_gb:":
            author.id.send("Hello")
        else:
            print(" ошибка туть")
    else:
        print("ошибка здесь")
client.run("token")
```

ошибка и в условии, и в отправке дс сообщения автору реакции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И зачем вам агрумент `self` если ви не используете класс, того вам и выдает что был упущен один аргумент:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    emoji = payload.emoji
    channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    author = message.author.id
    if message==id of message:
        if emoji == ":flag_gb:":
            member = client.get_user(author)
            member.send("Hello")
    await message.remove_reaction(emoji, author)
```

Comment: `channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id)` тогда чем заменить self?

Comment: Попробуйте так: `channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/uqzrrf не отправляется сообщение автору и + если заоментировать строку с удалением реакции то переменная author подсвечивается как неиспользуемая...на скрине все показано

Comment: изменил ответ, посмотрите

Comment: `author.id.send("Hello")`
так как вы перед этим указали переменную `author`

Comment: Добавляю реакцию, нр бот опять не прислал сообщение, и улалил реакцию

Comment: Усе извините вот окончательное решения [с документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-dm). Посмотрите, в ответ внес изменения.

Comment: Извините что так долго провтыкал этот момент

Comment: Та все ок, я пока вы "провтыкали" немного посмотрел код и обнаружил ошибку в условиях

Comment: В ближайшее время изменю вопрос

Comment: Не провтыкайте)